# What is the difference between \cs_if_exist:NTF and \cs_if_free:NTF?

Tags: latex3, expl3

I don't understand what difference of existance and being free means. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \my_cs: {}

\verb=\my_cs:= ~ does ~ \cs_if_exist:NF \my_cs: { not ~ } exist \\ % exists
\verb=\my_cs:= ~ is ~ \cs_if_free:NF \my_cs: { not } ~ free \\ % not free

\tl_new:N \l_my_tl

\verb=\l_my_tl= ~ does ~ \cs_if_exist:NF \l_my_tl { not ~ } exist \\ % exists
\verb=\l_my_tl= ~ is ~ \cs_if_free:NF \l_my_tl { not } ~ free % not free

\verb=\l_tmpa_tl=~does~\cs_if_exist:NF \l_tmpa_tl { not ~ } exist \\ % exists
\verb=\l_tmpa_tl=~is~\cs_if_free:NF \l_tmpa_tl { not } ~ free % not free

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Can a cs exist *and* be free? Or is the difference more a semantic one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I show the output of `\cs_show:N  \cs_if_free:NTF` and of `\cs_show:N \cs_if_exist:NTF` (formatted for better readability)

```
\cs_show:N \cs_if_free:NTF

> \cs_if_free:NTF=\long macro:
#1->\if_meaning:w #1\scan_stop:
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \if_cs_exist:N #1
        \prg_return_false:
      \else:
        \prg_return_true:
      \fi:
    \fi:
  \c_zero .

\cs_show:N \cs_if_exist:NTF

> \cs_if_exist:NTF=\long macro:
#1->\if_meaning:w #1\scan_stop:
      \prg_return_false:
    \else:
      \if_cs_exist:N #1
        \prg_return_true:
      \else:
        \prg_return_false:
      \fi:
    \fi:
  \c_zero .
```

If the meaning of `#1` is `\relax` (aka `\scan_stop:`), the former returns true  and the latter returns false, so `\relax` is free and does not exist. Otherwise the tests use `\if_cs_exist:N`, that is, `\ifdefined`, and the results are likewise opposite.

I think it's only a matter of convenience to have two tests that are, in fact, equivalent up to switching the arguments.

According to Joseph Wright, the two tests might have not been reverse of each other at some point in time, but they are nowadays.

Comment: Hmm... this means every existing command is not free and every free command does not exist. For me this sounds like the same thing with a different name. `\cs_if_exist:NT` _is_ the same as `\cs_if_free:NF` and vice versa.

Comment: Oh. I overread that you stated that in your answer as well :)

Comment: Yes and no. :) Try and see their meaning: `\cs_if_free:NF` seems to be slightly more efficient than `\cs_if_exist:NT` (and conversely, switching `F` and `T`).

Comment: I'm afraid I am not really able to tell what efficiency means in this context. Will the one be faster than the other? (Can't be much on a scale observable by human beings, anyway ;) )

Comment: A couple of expansions less, I'd say. Probably with some millions of tests you'd see some small difference. :)

Comment: As coded now in `expl3`, the `F` conditionals are slightly faster than the `T` conditionals. Really, I optimized the `TF` conditionals, and then the `F` conditionals come by just adding `{}`, while the `T` conditionals need `\use:n \use_none:n` to go from the `TF` logic to the `T` logic. This is true of _all_ conditionals in `expl3`. I try very hard not to take that into account when writing code because it may change (but as I'm perpetually striving for speed, that's difficult to forget).

Comment: Originally I somehow expected them to be different in some cases (besides the `true`/`false` switch). For example I expected a test for equality with `\relax` to be true in both cases.

Comment: Talking about `\relax` in this way would also be logical, but in expl3 by convention we set things up so that no control sequences should *ever* end up being set to `\relax` using the standard interfaces. (Unless I'm mistaken here, it would be considered a bug of expl3 for this to happen.) Of course you can always bypass this by using low-level functions `\cs:w...\cs_end:` but we hope that you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 7):

These commands were purposefully defined as a pair but their behaviour was not always symmetric. The original intention was to have a loose definition along the lines of:

`\cs_if_free:NTF` — is it *allowable* to create a new cs with this name?
`\cs_if_exist:NTF` — has the cs been created?

For quite a while, `\cs_if_free` had some extra branches to sanity check its input. E.g., only the kernel should define commands with `:D` suffixes, so return false. Actually that *might* have been the only difference `:)`. You could imagine a few other such checks according to the conventions of the `expl3` naming scheme.

As some point we decided that all this was overkill and simplified the behaviour, and at that point the two commands became logically symmetric. But I'd still recommend as a point of style to use them in your code according to the definitions above.

If we were to start again, I think it would be better to only have a single command name.

Comment: Thanks! This finally clears the reasoning behind those two.

Answer (score 5):

As egreg describes, the two conditionals can be used interchangeably in all cases (up to exchanging the `<true>` and `<false>` branches, of course).

The only difference is semantic. For instance,

```
\tl_new:N \l_foo_tl
```

starts with

```
\cs_if_free:NF \l_foo_tl { <error> }
```

but

```
\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl
```

contains roughly

```
\cs_if_exist:NF \l_foo_tl { <error> }
```

In both cases, we are trying to assert that a given condition holds: either check that the token list variable is free to define, or check that the token list is defined and won't trigger an error when used.